# Access to the path '\\Image0\Abc' is denied

Tags: asp.net

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("\\image0\Abc");
if (!directory.Exists)
{
    directory.Create();
}
```

When I user above ASP.NET code which UNC path, I found the following problem:

> Access to the path '\Image0\Abc' is denied.

How can I solve? Regards.

Comment: Do you mean \\Image0 as in the title or \Image0 as in the code?

Comment: Are you trying to access a network share from a web server/service? Is that allowed? Possibly if the account used by IIS is part of the domain but I doubt that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Network Service account to that folder if it is located outside your web application folder. If it is, there might be a problem in the path that you are accessing.